# Extending Laravel Mix to preprocess responsive images

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

My Laravel project doesn't require a database so something like using Spatie Laravel Media Library is out of the question.
I need to preprocess images into a variety of sizes and incorporating them into a srcset. Is it possible to run this process using Laravel Mix? All images would be stored in the public directory BTW.

This seems like a good starting point, but this just optimizes, not resizes them.
https://runningwebgeek.com/2018/05/laravel-mix-image-processing/

Plus a blade "shortcut" would be helpful to add the image to the page template like: `{{$image, 'image-name.png', 'alt-tag-name'}}`

Comment: This should not be the responsibility of mix itself in my opinion. Instead you can try creating (or using) a resizing library either for PHP as an artisan command or nodejs and run a resize task before you run mix

Comment: Write a custom command that you can call via Artisan. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands

Answer (score 0):

This is very rough, but it works.

Installed: [Laravel Mix Image Resizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix-image-resizer/v/0.0.5)

Blade component:

```php
@props(['alt','src','ext','sizes'])

@php $path = asset('img/'. $src . '.' . $ext) @endphp

<img alt="{{ $alt }}" src="{{ $path }}" srcset="

@foreach ($sizes as $i => $size) 
    @php $res_path = asset('img/' . $src . '-resized-' . $size . '.' . $ext . ' ' . $size . 'w') @endphp

    @php $size_last = end($sizes) @endphp

    {{ $res_path }} @if ($i < (count($sizes) - 1)){{ ', ' }} @endif
@endforeach 
" sizes="(max-width: {{ $size_last }}px) 100vw" />
```

Used in template:

```php
<x-image alt="" src="banner" ext="jpg" :sizes="[768, 1024, 1280, 1440, 1600]" />
```